# Nested list values returned by lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

Consider the following python code snippet:

```
scores = [[1, 35, 80], [2, 32, 75], [3, 30, 82], [4, 33, 75], [5, 37, 60]]
new_marks = map(lambda x: x[2]+2 if x[1]>=35 else x[2]-2, scores)
list(new_marks)
[82, 73, 80, 73, 62]
```

Why does this return only a list containing the modified values of x[2], rather than the original nested list with the modified values?

Comment: Because lambda returns either `x[2]+2` or `x[2]-2`.

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration through the original list (nested list, in this case) the lambda function returns the value produced by evaluation of the expression following the colon.  In this case, the expression to be evaluated is "x[2]+2 if..." or "else x[2]-2"...single values.

In order to have lambda return a *list*, you must specify a list as the value to be returned, as in the answer supplied by sagi.  In this case, the list might include the unmodified values of x[0] and x[1], and the modified value of x[2], all contained by the square brackets that specify a list.

(Thank you, sagi.)